# Cannot add jwt token to node.js response

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I'm new to javascript ecosystem and want to add jwt token to response out of this registration router:

```
router.post('/register', (req, res)=> {

    User.findOne({email: req.body.email})
     .then(user => {
        if(user) {
            return res.status(400).json({error: 'Email already exists'});
        } else {                    
            const newUser = new User({
                username: req.body.username,
                email: req.body.email,
                password: req.body.password
            });

            bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt)=> {
                bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash)=> {
                    if (err)  throw err;
                    newUser.password = hash;
                    newUser.save()                      
                      .then(user => res.status(200).json(user)) //<=Problem is here
                      .catch(err => console.log(err));
                } )
            })
        }
     })

});
```

The jwt snippet (which works fine on `longin` router) is this:

```
        const payload = {
            username: user.username
        }

        //sign token
        jwt.sign(
            payload, 
            keys.secretOrKey, 
            { expiresIn: 3600}, 
            (err, token)=> { 
                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    token: 'Bearer '+ token,
                    username: username
                });
            });
```

The problem is that I don't know how can I add the snippet to the response header.
When I add it after `.then(user =>` I get a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token const` error.

How can I make it?

Comment: Did you add the jwt snippet behind ```.then(user =>``` using curly braces wrapping the snippet?

Comment: Yes, I just coped the snipped you see above  after `.then(user => `

Comment: [Authenticate a Node.js API with JSON Web Tokens](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens)

Comment: @Momin My question is how to integrate signed jwt token into existing promise. The link you mentioned is not helpful about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you didn't wrap the jwt snippet within curly braces. Without them the arrow function where the problem appears only takes one expression. Paste the jwt snippet into the following snippet instead.

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt)=> {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash)=> {
    if (err)  throw err;
    newUser.password = hash;
    newUser.save()                      
        .then(user => {
          res.status(200).json(user);
          <JWT_Snippet_here>
        }
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    })
})
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Basic_Syntax) you can see how the syntax of arrow functions is defined. The following quote shows the most important part.

> (param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements }
>
> (param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression

Curly braces are needed in order to be able to use a list of statements. The error you experienced occurred because your JavaScript engine expected a single expression but instead found a list of statements.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This resolved the error, but I still do not receive the token in response header in the browser's console. `res.data.token` is `undefined`